# How to write the words one under the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, cpu-word

When I enter this code, it just seems like this:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQFR2.jpg)

But it should be word by word for each line, not letter by letter. I can't solve it, so here is my code:

```
siir = "Karşında ziya yoksa, sağından ya solundan. Tek bir ışık olsun buluver, kalma yolundan."

print(*siir[0:len(siir)], sep="\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Try splitting the words into a list, and then joining the list from there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because the code is provided as a screenshot. It should be transcribed to text (and then it can be reopened).

Answer (score 0):

To use that approach you must split it into a list of strings first.

```
print(*siir.split(),sep="\n")
```

although I prefer

```
print(siir.replace(" ","\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
print(*siir.split(), sep="\n")
```

And get a list of words.

You do not need to do this: `.split(" ")` because it is the default.